# How to add UITabBarItem via storyboard that conditionally loads a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

My app has a `UITabBarController` as root and I have a "Profile" tab. I'm using storyboards, and I want the Profile tab to load a "sessionless version" where it only shows login and sign up buttons, and a "sessioned" one where it has the Profile badge and other things logged in users can do (edit account, sign out, etc).

What I tried: So the three other tabs are `UINavigationControllers` attached to the tab bar, and I tried adding a Tab Bar Item to the `UITabBarController` via storyboard, but I can't. I was planning to put the two Profile screens in the same storyboard and segue to them by implementing `didSelectItem` in my tab bar controller's owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, dummy. Of course I can just add a `UINavigationController` as the Profile tab in Interface Builder, and conditionally make its root view controller a sessioned or sessionless screen in code.